# How can i remove inline styles when copied text nodes from div which has contenteditable attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While I write code a copy function for text rich editor, got a problem.
When I trying to get text which stored from div which has contenteditable attribute into clipboard, it wrapped by many inline styles.
I don't want to wrapped it inline styles, because body size will be increase.

1. define div tag and paste event

```
    <div contenteditable id="test" style="min-width:600px; min-height: 800px;"/>
    
    document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("paste", (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.clipboardData.getData("text/html")); 
    })
```

2. write some text into div tag.
3. select range substrings and copy.
4. it will be printed like under.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Apple SD Gothic Neo&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;">sdasdasdas</span>
```

How can I get a copied text that only has exactly in line styles what i intend like below?

`<span>sdasdasdas</span>` 
or
`<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">sdasdasdas</span>`

Comment: Just remove the style attribute before pasting the element?

Comment: @Teemu No, I want to remove only inline styles that added by browser. (I suspect that browser add some styles along environment around for text node)

If I add some inline styles, it should remain in the tag.

Comment: I doubt a browser would add any inline styles on its own ... Then don't add inline styles, use CSS instead, then you can remove a "browser added inline style".